# Change the category of all posts in it

Tags: categories, mysql

I'm trying to make a category change of some posts by MySQL.

But I am not able to give the update in the database, it is giving error when running the query.

```
UPDATE *
FROM mooca_posts
LEFT JOIN mooca_term_relationships ON (mooca_posts.ID = mooca_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN mooca_term_taxonomy ON (mooca_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = mooca_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
SET mooca_term_taxonomy.term_id = '112'
WHERE mooca_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (1448)
GROUP BY mooca_posts.ID
```

I need to change from category 1448 to 112.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships 
  SET term_taxonomy_id = 112
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 1448
```

Try this